# php pdo code for for loop to insert values in sequence order /increment order

Tags: php, pdo

plz suggest me

**what i need is ..when i entered 5 in book_no txtbox then insert 5 rows in**

**database and values goes in book_no column like 1,2,3,4,5,,,,like wise...**

**plz suggest me what to change in my for loop....**

**below code works perfect but values not going in sequential order...**

```
$book_no = $_POST['book_no'];                   
                for($row=1;$row<=$book_no;$row++)
                {
                $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,created) VALUES (:book_no,:created)", 
                array(':book_no'=>$book_no,':created'=>$created));
                }
```

Comment: I think you need to save $row as value to take 1,2,3,4,5 as values... I don't understand at all what you need...

Comment: i need is how to select max value from table and this value get in loop .. for ex-- in my table there are 3 rows and value in book_no col in 1,2,3...ok  now when i insert 4 rows again then no goes in book_no column from 4,5,6,7,..like wise....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
':book_no'=>$book_no
```

with this:

```
':book_no'=>$row
```

Comment: plz suggest how to get max value from database  and loop insert query  $book_no = $_POST['book_no'];     
     $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
     for($row=1;$row<=$book_no;$row++)
     {
     $query = $database->getrows("SELECT MAX(book_no) as maxbook_no FROM scheme_master"); 
     $max =  $query['maxbook_no'] + 1; 
     $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,created) VALUES (:book_no,:created)", 
     array(':book_no'=>$max,':created'=>$created));
     }

Answer (score 0):

Ok understood, I think you need to set auto increment in mysql to desired value. This would solve your problem?

If not, you can use lastInsertId method from PDO
[link](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php)